# Rails PHP Login Integration

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I have an application in rails (uses authentication via AuthLogic).

I want to login to my PHP application by remotely logging on to my rails app. 
I want the PHP app to use my Rails app to perform the authentication and retrieve user details on a successful login else echo error from my rails app.

In shorter words,
Login form in PHP -> Submit credentials to Rails app -> retrieve results of rails app back to php application.

How can I go about this ??

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to approach this. But there are some rules to make this setup workable. Firstly, you need to make sure that both your Rails and PHP app are on the same domain and can read each others cookies. You will need to store and session in the cookie, or give both your PHP and Rails app access to the same session store. This is tricky at best.

My solution would be to use an existing authentication methods. Either implement an OpenID or oauth provider in your PHP app. Those are readily available on the web. On the Rails side you'd implement an OpenID or oauth consumer. By not building your own solution and using a proven concept like OpenID or oauth you are adding a lot more safety to your app than with a self-made solution.

By the way, there's nothing wrong with adding your own toppings to the OpenID or oauth schemes. I.e. I have built an app once with a central authentication server using OpenID. But we had the client apps 'auto approved' and we were able so send basic user info to the clients (like ID, email, name, addresses etc.)

Again, my advise is to go with OpenID or oauth. I think the latter is simpler to implement (and Twitter uses it).

Comment: The reason to opt for OpenID or oauth is also that there are libraries available for both Ruby and PHP and you won't have to worry about PHP<->Ruby talking to each other directly through session stores or anything crazy like that.